# Is there a way to switch between plots in R?

Tags: r, plot, graph

Is there a way to switch between plots in R?

Here, I have two plots

```
xs <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
ys <- c(3, 4, 1, 2)
p <- c(0.25, 0.33, 0.42)
par(mfrow=c(1, 2))
plot(xs, ys)
pie(p)

# ----------------------------
# Here I what to go back to my 
# first plot to add some lines
# ----------------------------

lines(xs, ys)
```

How do I accomplish this?

Any thing would help, thanks.

Comment: See ?dev.set and related functions.

Comment: Neat function, but sadly, I want to switch between plots in the same window. Do you know any ways of achieving that?

Comment: In base R (not RStudio), one can enable "History" (on windows, *History > Recording*), and use `PgUp`/`PgDn` to navigate to previous/next plots (respectively). While on a previous plot, you can add to it with `lines(.)` if needed, though the new additions are not preserved in the history. For instance, `plot(1)` then `plot(2)`, then `PgUp` will bring you back to the first; `points(1.1, 1.1)` will add that one point to the `plot(1)` plot, which is what you want. Unfortunately, if you `PgDn` (to plot 2) then `PgUp` (back to plot 1), the added points are no longer present.

Comment: In RStudio, the plots are already recording history, and the left/right blue arrows (depending on your OS theme) mimic the `PgUp`/`PgDn`. Interestingly, `points()` are preserved in the recording history.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the `mfg` argument to `par` that specifically addresses this. From `?par`:

> ‘mfg’:
>
> A numerical vector of the form ‘c(i, j)’ where ‘i’ and ‘j’
> indicate which figure in an array of figures is to be drawn
> next (if setting) or is being drawn (if enquiring).  The
> array must already have been set by ‘mfcol’ or ‘mfrow’.

This is not enough: when you switch, the user coordinates are kept from the last figure drawn. Consider this example:

```
par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
plot(1:10)
plot(1:100)
par(mfg = c(1,1))
lines(1:10, 1:10, col = "red")
```

You will see that correctly the figure drawn by `lines` is the leftmost, but the red line is actually shorter than expected, covering only a small region of the plot area. You have to manually cache the coordinates of the first figure before switching. This works, exploiting the `usr` parameter:

```
par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
plot(1:10)
oldusr <- par()$usr
plot(1:100)
par(mfg = c(1,1), usr = oldusr)
lines(1:10, 1:10, col = "red")
```

Of course, if you intend to switch between figures back and forth, you need to cache the `usr` of each after calling `plot` and use them before switching.

The solution applied to your example:

```
xs <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
ys <- c(3, 4, 1, 2)
p <- c(0.25, 0.33, 0.42)
par(mfrow=c(1, 2))
plot(c(1, 2, 3, 4), c(3, 4, 1, 2))
oldusr <- par()$usr
pie(p)
par(mfg = c(1,1), usr = oldusr)
lines(xs, ys)
```